"alternatives" tag

Possible Duplicate:
Should questions that are about a specific alternate blockchain be tagged alternative-blockchains? 

I think the "alternatives" tag is pointless and harmful, and it would be better to have specific tags for each currency.
This is because it encompasses both currencies with a sane goal that makes sense, like Namecoin, and stupid currencies with no other reason than to "play" like tenebrix and the like.
I don't think it's fair to put them in the same bag.

Quite disappointed (unsurprised, though) Stack didn't bother to notify me of the closed post.

posted it here: http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9/should-questions-that-are-about-a-specific-alternate-blockchain-be-tagged-altern/222#222
